# Execute insert query, only if count rows equals x

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$res = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM table")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ( $res[0]['cnt'] == 0 ) {

   $db->query("
   INSERT INTO table (col) 
   VALUES
   ('value1'),
   ('value2'),
   ('value3'),
   ....
   ");

}
```

Suppose  2 users requested this code same time,

So, for first user, count will return `0` and INSERT  query will executed, but there is possible that while first insert executed, for second user, count return also `0` ? (and in this case second insert query will  also executed, what I don't need).

If this is possible, how to prevent this? Using `Transactions` will help in  such cases ?

Comment: I assume the only command to retrieve PDO results known to you is fetchAll()?

Comment: No need to use fetchAll, use fetchcolumn - you are only selecting 1 integer value from COUNT: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php

Comment: pdo transactions are automatically set to auto-commit unless otherwise set. Which means, there's already a transaction: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php

Unfortunately, not every database supports transactions, so PDO needs to run in what is known as "auto-commit" mode when you first open the connection. Auto-commit mode means that every query that you run has its own implicit transaction, if the database supports it, or no transaction if the database doesn't support transactions.

Comment: @wribit you have missed both question and the meaning of auto-commit

Comment: @Your Common Sense, user4035 -  Thanks for side notes.

Comment: there was no question, or meaning of auto-commit meant. There was just reference to the manual stating "... every query that you run has its own implicit transaction." The OP was asking about transactions and if they would help. This was meant to show that, well not really. I find you quite snide, sir.

Comment: @wribit there is a question (and even an answer, if you didn't notice). While your comment doesn't explain why transactions won't help, as autocommit has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I'm not going to reply here, but if you want to continue this in chat I'd be more than happy to... this isn't the venue for conversations. I stand by what I posted though, since it wasn't meant in the way you took it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to insert only if there are no records in the table. Transactions won't help you.

You can use a WRITE LOCK:

> Only the session that holds the lock can access the table. No other session can access it until the lock is released.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

Use the following method:

```
mysql> LOCK TABLES t1 WRITE;

mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1;

mysql> INSERT INTO t1 (col) 
   VALUES
   ('value1'),
   ('value2'),
   ('value3');

mysql> UNLOCK TABLES;
```

If another session tries to execute the command `LOCK TABLES t1 WRITE;`, it will wait until the first session finishes. So COUNT will always return the correct value.